# Looking for an email (IMAP) client for a Windows computer with low disk space

Tags: windows, email, gmail, imap

I would like recommendations for an email client with low (and configurable) disk space utilization, for Windows. Good Gmail support is a big plus.

Thanks.

Comment: What features do you want in it? POP3 support? IMAP support? Rich text rendering? HTML rendering? How do you define 'good GMail support'? Why doesn't a web browser satisfy this requirement? As written, this question is uselessly broad; please provide more detail regarding your requirements.

Comment: beside that how much disk-space it will consume over all at the end will mainly depend on how you configure your client to handle/download/save your mails on you local computer. - not to mention your chosen protocol (IMAP/POP3)!

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  Gmail is IMAP, but has peculiarities. For example, it allows the user to attach multiple tags to emails. Some email clients support this by making each tag a folder, and creating multiple copies of the message. I wonder if there is a better way. HTML rendering is necessary. Rich Text is not, because it's normally converted to HTML. Gmail's web interface is adequate, barely, but it could be much better.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy True, of course, but i was wondering if somewhere, in this vast world, someone has created an imap client that is careful with disk usage.

Comment: Your requirements are still very broad; please [edit] the question to provide more detail. (I should note that I am using GMail with a pure POP3/SMTP client, but I also don't use GMail's tagging.)

Comment: @theglauber: *I wonder if there is a better way.* -- well... i don't get it why to use this incompatible google-specials at all!? simply use the IMAP-compliant folders and tags (also multiple possible) which are also synced to every client. and if you want the same email to appear in different folders, create virtual folders aka. saved searches/filters in your client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i may suggest [**Thunderbird**](https://www.thunderbird.net/), but no idea if it fits your bill since your requirements are still very vague...

but at least i can tell:

- it is FOSS and multiplatform available for Windows, MacOS and Linux.
- beside IMAP, POP3 and SMTP it also supports XMPP, Newsfeeds, etc.
- the disk space usage of the programm itself is - compared to other lightweight mail-clients - not that small, but sightly smaller compared to MS Outlook.
- you can set the usage of disk storage for every account separately and limit it by folder, size or time.
- you also have an option to completely delete messages more than a specified number or older than a defined time.
- html and plain text is supported for reading and writing.
- a learning spam-filter is also included.
- it has a pretty good advanced filter, which can be saved as virtual folders.
- marking messages and tagging is also supported and synced (via IMAP).
- it also provides a system for add-ons which add numerous functions like [CardBook](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/cardbook/) (advanced address-book with CardDAV-support), [Lightning](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/lightning/) (calendar with CalDAV-support), [Enigmail](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/enigmail/) (PGP-encryption),...

---

i have no idea about a google-support, since i don't use it and IMHO it isn't necessary at all. if it isn't induced (in a satisfying way), maybe you can find something at https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/.

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly, i started with Thunderbird, and it seems i'm staying with it, at least for now.